# override spring bean in a jar file

Tags: spring

I have a dao jar file that contains all the domain objects and service classes. it has a config file `dao-resource.xml` with `id=datasource`.

I am using this jar file in another project which has its own `app-context.xml`, but i want to override the bean with `id="datasource"` in the jar file

how do i do this. I tried to add a bean with same id in `app-context.xml` and added both files to classpathxmlapplicat.... first `dao-resource.xml` then `app-context.xml`

but that did not seem to work.

how else can i override a bean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having spring config files in jars makes things a bit harder to manage. If you have annotated your classes it would be easier.

But anyway, I'd suggest splitting the dao xml in two parts - your beans, and infrastructure-related beans (like the datasource). Then you can include only the ones you need in your app-context.xml.

Another way would be to use `primary="true"` on your overriding bean. This would mean all injection points that need a bean of type `DataSource`, would pick your primary bean. But that won't work if you refer to your datasource in your dao xml.

So in short - you can't override a bean, so split your xml file and include only the parts you need.